# Get hold of AngularJS Object from inside javascript to open bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, rootscope

The logout() has the code to open model. I only want logout() function to be called if the angularjs object value inside rootscope is true..  How do I check from javascript what is inside the rootscope object?

```
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <div id="myPopup" modal custom-model fade" style="left:20%"
            data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="custom-modal-header">
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-modal-body">
                    </div>
                    <div class="custom-modal-footer">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  



<script type="text/javascript">
logout();//here add if rootscope.mydata == true 
</script>  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer would be, inject `$rootScope` into your controller:

```
angular
    .module("yourAppName")
    .controller("myController", function ($rootScope) {
        // $rootScope is available here!
        if ($rootScope..mydata) {
            // show modal?
        }
    })
```

You didn't specify what you wanted to start the `logout` function, a button click or when the controller loads, so adjust it as you see fit.